# How to read and parse an XML file from Jelly Template in Jenkins?

Tags: xml, jenkins, jelly

I'm trying to read and parse an XML file which is located in the workspace of the job.

I want to access this file from customized Email-ext jelly template and read the file and then parse it , so that I can find the error tags in the xml and identify the errors.

But I'm unable to access the file in the workspace from Jelly custom template and I'm getting either of the two exceptions ::::

**JellyException:null::::: /home/.../workspace/${project.name}/errors.xml (No such file or directory) Nested exception: /home/.../workspace/${project.name}/errors.xml (No such file or directory)**

OR

**JellyException: Could not parse Jelly script : null**

I'm using the following tags : x:parse, x:forEach

Thanks in advance!!